# Fairness of G-d’s choice of Moses and Bilam?

Tags: nevua-prophecy, parashat-balak, bilam

The Gemmorah claims that Bilam was given as a prophet to the nations comparable to Moses.

I, however see some unfairness in this choice:

- Moses was born good - he was already circumsized and the whole house was filled with light (apparently everybody recognized that).
- Bilam was agreeably a greedy sinner (acc. to practically all the interpreters)

How was this choice fair? How the selection of a sinner to represent the nations can be compared to the selection of Moses?

Comment: Isn't the claim that they had the same potential, and Bilam misused it? "Bilam was agreeably a greedy sinner" sounds like a learned behavior, which proves the point that he misused his potential.

Comment: @Salmononius2 same potential like in Megamind. Like with Eisov and Yaakov - one was born ugly and one handsome and you wonder how come that one becomes a Tzadik and another a Wicked. G-d designated Moses before he was born, so he was born great, where do we see Bilam born great?

Comment: What I want to know, and cannot find anywhere, is WHAT Balaam prophesied to the Gentiles (other than to Balak).

Comment: Maybe the gentiles needed someone they could relate to, to create a chance that they might listen to his prophecies and act accordingly?

Comment: Please bring the source that Bilam is supposed to be an equivalent parallel to Moshe. Rashi on Bamidbar 22:5 does not mention equivalency, just that there is a prophet among the non-Jews.

Comment: @Salmononius2 -- This midrash clearly implies equivalence: "[The Torah says:] And there has not arisen since, in Israel, a prophet [like Moses] [Deut. 34:10]. In Israel there had not arisen one like him, but there had arisen one like him among the nations of the world. This was in order that the nations of the world might have no excuse for saying: If we had possessed a prophet like Moses, we would have worshipped the Holy One, blessed be He.  What prophet did they have that was like Moses? Balaam the son of Beor. [Numbers Rabbah 14:20]

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi I showed clearly that wasn't the case - they were not equal, Bilaam was destined to fail.